# Is it good practice to use Angular Flex-Layout?

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular6, angular-flex-layout

I would like to know if it really is a good practice to use Angular Flex-Layout module. Isn't it just sugar coated inline styles with extra performance cost since it's  JavaScript that does the styling?
So if you can, please explain to me why I should use it over basic flex box?

Answer (score 5):

caution: the answer may vary based on user opinion

If you are already flexbox in your css.
I would **not recommend** to try out angular flex box packages as of now.

If you are freshly building some application, you can try that time.

However, the package still in **beta**. If I'm building a PROD application I wont use beta packages in my project. All you have to do is wait for major release to use in PROD version of application.

I'm just highlighting a comment in the github repo
(https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/674#issuecomment-374866400)

> The reason for the perpetual beta stage of the project is because a
>   lot of the functionality of the project has yet to be finalized. As
>   you may have noticed over the past few weeks, we've introduced a **ton**
>   **of** **breaking changes between betas**. Not to mention the changes we have
>   in the pipeline (switching to the CDK layout engine for one), most of
>   which are going to have to wait until the Ivy renderer has been
>   completed (which will be well past v6).
>
> While the functionality of many of the core directives remains stable,
>   we are still tweaking them and trying to improve them. And then there
>   are the performance hits from using a directive-based layout library
>   that we hope to resolve when the Ivy renderer comes out.
>
> We understand the frustration/turn-off of using a project still in
>   beta, but it gives us the flexibility to improve the project at a
>   faster pace for now while we work out what the "stable" version of the
>   library will look like. We'll hopefully have more updates on this over
>   the next few months as Ivy is finalized and we can settle on a design.

If you are beginner and want to try out this package in any small level project, just try out and be aware of breaking changes between beta version releases.

Comment: Your answer aged well, as [flex layout has now been deprecated](https://blog.angular.io/modern-css-in-angular-layouts-4a259dca9127), and is no longer even supported in Angular v16+

Comment: 6 years old now

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer comes late, but I've had this question myself after stumbling over the package. I normally just use CSS flexbox as it's very simple and I don't find it having a lot of boilerplate for getting quick results. To me the library looks pretty much sugar coated styles as you put it and I don't know about the performance penalty, however I found a link with some examples which basically show rather biggish CSS code reduction in favor of adding directives:
https://indepth.dev/angular-flex-layout-flexbox-and-grid-layout-for-angular-component

I have also looked at CSS libraries solutions with helper classes that also reduce custom CSS usage, are made with responsiveness in mind, etc. such as https://tailwindcss.com/. If there really is any performance drawback with using directives based styling I would opt for CSS only based solutions.

Comment: I would go with tailwind nowadays easily.